# Executable Started From Named Pipe?

Tags: windows, named-pipes

Can someone please tell me how this was done? Take a look at the "Command Line" for `SmcGui.exe`. You will notice that it's a Named Pipe string... The full string is:

```
\\.\pipe\SygateSecurityAgentR41T67564 \\.\pipe\SygateSecurityAgentW18467T67564
```

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

Comment: Looks like they are just command line arguments; same as vcpkgsrv.exe.  Whoever is launching the process is not following the convention of including the process name as the first argument of the command line (e.g. via CreateProcess).

Comment: If the process name was not the first argument, then how could the application have started?

Comment: It is a fluke of CreateProcess(), two ways to specify the .exe name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN docs on [CreateProcess][1]

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpApplicationName,
  __inout_opt  LPTSTR lpCommandLine,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
  __in_opt     LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  __in         BOOL bInheritHandles,
  __in         DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  __in_opt     LPVOID lpEnvironment,
  __in_opt     LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
  __in         LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
  __out        LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
);
```

> *lpApplicationName* [in, optional]
>
> The name of the module to be
>   executed. This module can be a Windows-based application. It can be
>   some other type of module (for example, MS-DOS or OS/2) if the
>   appropriate subsystem is available on the local computer.
>
> The string
>   can specify the full path and file name of the module to execute or it
>   can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the
>   function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the
>   specification. The function will not use the search path. This
>   parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension
>   is assumed.
>
> **The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL**. In that case,
>   the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the
>   lpCommandLine string.

Comment: After testing a call to CreateProcess specifying the `ApplicationName` attribute, I was able to replicate that. Apparently the "Command Line" property in the process viewer does not behave the way I understood it to.